# Why GraphQL Subscriptions will remove the query when update?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have the following subscription but when I receive something in and try to update the query it will be removed. Any idea what am I doing wrong in this? All my subscriptions are working well apart of this and the only difference is that I am receiving an array instead of an object.

```
if (nextProps.getSkills && !nextProps.getSkills.loading) {
  let { subscribeToMore } = this.props.getSkills;
  subscribeToMore({
    document: SKILLS_ENDORSED_SUBSCRIPTION,
    updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
      if (!subscriptionData.data) {
        return prev;
      }

      const endorsedSkills = subscriptionData.data.skillsEndorsed;

      if (endorsedSkills) {
        return {
          ...prev,
          getUserSkills: [...endorsedSkills, ...prev.getUserSkills]
        };
      }

      return prev;
    },
    onError: err => console.log(err)
  });
}
```

My query before updating

```
Object {
  "error": undefined,
  "fetchMore": [Function bound ],
  "getUserSkills": Array [], // When I update this will be removed
  "loading": false,
  "networkStatus": 7,
  "refetch": [Function bound ],
  "startPolling": [Function bound ],
  "stopPolling": [Function bound ],
  "subscribeToMore": [Function bound ],
  "updateQuery": [Function bound ],
  "variables": Object {},
}
```

Comment: Odd. Might be helpful to see your full component code, including all HOCs and lifecycle hooks. I'm guessing this code is running inside `componentWillUpdate`?

Comment: @DanielRearden it is running in `ComponentWillReceiveProps`, I have other subscriptions inside but all are working well. If I `console.log(endorsedSkills)` I can see that the array is received but when it comes to update the previews array will remove `getUserSkills`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the logic inside `updateQuery` is correct. That's why I'm wondering if there's something else in your component that's causing that one property to get dropped.

Comment: @DanielRearden nothing else. All my subscriptions look the same but this one seem to not work. if I use this `getUserSkills: [...prev.getUserSkills]` will update without any error.

Comment: "Without any error"... so do you see an error in the console otherwise?

Comment: @DanielRearden in render I am looking for the length of `getUserSkills` but because it is not there anymore when `updateQuery` it will come with `TypeError`